# Create NSURL with string containing "^" character gives a nil

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsurl

When i try to creating an `NSURL` with a `String` containing "`^`" character the app crashs and the console says:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

does any faced this before ?

**EDIT:**

It seems that the NSURL initializer gives a nil object, and the app crashs when trying to enforce unwrapping it.

how can i avoid getting this nil instance of NSURL with String containing such character?

**EDIT**

Here is some code, to clarify things:

```
let searchMethod = "advancedsearch.php?"
let searchParameters = "q=title:Book^100%20OR%20description:Book^15%20OR%20collection:Book^10%20OR%20language:Book^10%20OR%20text:Book^1&mediatype:texts+AND+NOT+hidden:true+AND+collection:texts&sort%5B%5D=titleSorter+asc&rows=10&output=json&start=1"
NSURL(string:"\(baseURL)/\(searchMethod)\(searchParameters)")
print("url \(url)")
```

The NSURL is nil,console gives :

```
url nil
```

Comment: Give us a clue- add some code!

Comment: Google add percent escape using URL character sets host or query allowed characters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33147731/edit

Answer (score 0):

"`^`" symbol is not allowed for URL encoding.
Use this one for swift:

```
let encodedURLString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Or for Objective-C:

```
NSString *encodedURLString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: There is a character set for every component of the URL you should apply them to to their respective components